# How to append !important to an inline css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It's really hard for me to figure this out. But can anyone give me a sample script where I can just add !important to an already existing inline css?

Answer (score 3):

You can add !important to inline using below code,

Suppose you want to add `inline` css for `div` tag then you can do that using below code.

**CSS way**

```
<div style="color:red !important"
```

**jQuery**

```
$('div').attr('style', 'color:red !important;');
```

Comment: I believe this will overwrite any existing inline styles.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the inline styles using the [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), and manipulate them like below,

```
var styleCode = $('p').attr('style').split(";");
$('p').attr('style',styleCode.join(' !important;'));
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nhJW/1/)

Answer (score 1):

[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$(element).attr('style', 'height:200px !important;')
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="yourelementclass"></div>
```

JS Code

```
  $('.yourelementclass').attr('style', 'width:500px !important;')
```

Here is **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/srSaS/)**

Answer (score 1):

A non-library specific way would be to use the += operator to append `!important` to the value.

`<div style="width:50px;" id="id1"></div>`

`document.getElementById("id1").style.width += " !important";`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img')[0].style.setProperty( 'width', '500px', 'important' );
```